# NuGet, Entity Framework and MVC

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, nuget

I am new here! :)

I had a question about NuGet, Entity Framework and MVC overall.

I understand MVC is Model view control. Entity framework is ORM. Is there relationship between the two? I do not use .NET so it is NOT MVC right? (Cause there is not view)

What is the relationship between NuGet and Entity Framework and NuGet?

Thanks

Comment: This might be a better question for the Programmers site. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76890/what-is-the-difference-between-stackoverflow-and-programmers-stackexchange)

Comment: Nuget is just a package manager that you can use to install different frameworks/plugins.  I would suggest doing a tutorial on MVC with Entity to get a basic grasp of the systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MVC** - Is as you said Model-View-Controller programming modeling based which is used everywhere, not just in C#. It is also used in PHP, JAVA and alot of other programming languages, so it is just type of model of programming.

**.NET** - Is a framework which's purpose is to help people programming with everything they need into web, for things like: 
**HTTP
XML
SOAP
UDDI**
. Basically, it has preconfigured, and lots of libraries inside which does the job for you, so you dont have to deal with a lot web configuring stuff.

**Entity Framework**  - It is a framework, which can be used from someone who is already using the **.NET** framework, it is like an extension of **.NET** framework. It's main purpose is to map developers code and project, so they can have an easier interaction between Database and Code literally. Plenty of options are in EntityFramework, which allows you to write one part of the program(code modeling), and **EF**(entityFramework) turns it into a Table, or Database, and also vice versa.

**NuGet** - And this is just one open-source package manager, which allows you to install custom developing tools, install new libraries, to make your project easier to develop.

Hope you got it all right, and good luck on the best programming enviroment, **.NET!**